# Qt: function returns object, putting it into a pointer

Tags: qt

Hopefully this isn't too stupid but I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Some Qt functions return Qt objects as values, but we may want to store them in a pointer somewhere.  For example, in QDomDocument, the function documentElement returns a QDomElement, not a pointer to it.  Now, as a member of my class I have:

```
QDomElement *listRootElement;
```

In a function that sets things up I am using this:

```
listRootElement = new QDomElement;
*listRootElement = mainIndex->documentElement();
```

(mainIndex is a QDomDocument.)

This seems to work, but I just want to make sure I'm doing it right and that nothing will come back to bite me.

It would be very similar for some of the image functions where a QPixmap might be returned, and I want to maintain pointers to QPixMap's.

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: A bit more to it - it seems a bit of a waste to construct an empty element.  And worse, what if it is a class with no default constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to store a pointer to a `QDomElement` for some reason, and assuming that you aware of the potential pitfalls with pointers (like, two pointers might point to the same object):

The only thing to keep in mind is that the popular 'parent takes care of deleting children' system which Qt uses is only available for `QObject` (sub-)classes. So when `new`'ing a `QString` or a `QDomElement` or something like that, keep in mind that you *do* have to `delete` it yourself, too.

Comment: Good call I just added appropriate deletes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but I think this:

```
listRootElement = new QDomElement(mainIndex->documentElement());
```

...may allow the compiler to optimise better (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for some reasoning).

Comment: Ok. I *do* want to be able to edit the DOM and save it from elsewhere in the program.  Is there a way to do this without creating the copy?

Comment: @Micah - I think I'm wrong about that. Usually, changing a copy doesn't affect the original - but these are just wrappers around an internal structure that *is* modified using the object's methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the initially allocated object:

```
QDomElement *listRootElement; // undefined ptr value, I'd prefer null or new right away
listRootElement = new QDomElement;
*listRootElement = mainIndex->documentElement();
```

You're essentially doing:

```
int *x = new int(42);
*x = 47;
```

This works because both QDomElement and int implements the assignment operator (=).

Note that there's no need to delete anything, as the returned temporary is copied into your newly allocated object.